# Wolfram Alpha Solution Entry

Tags: wolframalpha

Using this Wolfram Alpha code either through web or in Mathematica:

```
(5y^4+3y^2+e^y)y'=cos(x),y(0)=0
```

My equation seems to be properly parsed:

```
{(5 y(x)^4 + 3 y(x)^2 + e^(y(x))) y'(x) = cos(x), y(0) = 0}
```

As a separable DE, the result should be:

```
y^5 + y^3 + e^y = sin(x) + 1
```

How do I modify the original Wolfram Alpha code to get the program to evaluate the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using Wolfram Alpha

```
{(5y[x]^4+3y[x]^2+E^y[x])y'[x]==Cos[x],y[0]==0} solution
```

[image]

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much!